# Django + Apache WSGI + pscopg2 + PostgreSQL 9.1 unexpected EOF on client connection

Tags: postgresql, connection

There are two servers I have. One is SQL server, other is Django project server. And sometimes I get too many `unexpected EOF on client connection` error by postgresql and `OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out` error by django project sametime. DB connection handled by Django itself. And I can't find out what is the problem. Does anybody has an opinion?

SQL server setup are as follows:

- 16 GB RAM
- i7-3770 CPU
- shmmax 8356163584
- PostgreSQL server 9.1 ([Postgresql Config](http://pastebin.com/azLSbyRR))
- Running on Ubuntu 12 64 bit Server LTS

Project server setup are as follows:

- 8 GB RAM
- i7-920 CPU
- Apache 2
- Django 1.3
- Python 2.6
- with pscopg2
- running on Ubuntu 10 64 bit Server LTS

With this setup I have some postgresql connection issues like below:

**Postgresql.log :**

```
2013-10-23 12:23:23 CEST LOG: SSL error: bad write retry 
2013-10-23 12:23:23 CEST LOG: could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer 
2013-10-23 12:23:23 CEST LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer 
2013-10-23 12:23:23 CEST LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection 
2013-10-23 12:24:37 CEST LOG: could not send data to client: Broken pipe
```

**Project Apache log** Logged many of them per request:

```
[Wed Oct 23 12:22:36 2013] [error] Premature end of script headers: wsgi, referer: http://x.com/online/
```

**Django Error mails** dropped to my box per request:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "y.com" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port xxx?
```

**mtr results** for may gives any clue:

```
mtr -s 1500 -r -c 1000 -i 0.1 y.com
HOST: x.com                        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1. static.xxx.xxx.x.188.clients  0.0%  1000    0.8   1.4   0.6   8.0   1.2
  2. hos-tr4.juniper2.rz10.hetzne  0.0%  1000    0.3   4.2   0.2 176.7  16.5
  3. core22.hetzner.de             0.0%  1000    0.4   0.4   0.3  25.3   1.5
  4. juniper4.rz16.hetzner.de      0.0%  1000    0.3   5.5   0.3 273.6  23.7
  5. hos-tr6.ex3k16.rz16.hetzner.  0.0%  1000    3.8   2.3   1.0  22.8   2.0
  6. y.com                         0.0%  1000    0.6   0.6   0.4  27.7   1.1
```

Comment: db clients go through WAN to reach db server?

Comment: Yes, but they are located in same hosting.